# Display seconds as ddd:hh:mm:ss (MySQL & jsp)

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have a table (MySQL) with a duration (in seconds) column

```
id   asset  name    zone    Duration
1    1234   Fred    2       330364
2    1234   Fred    1       78921
3    1234   Fred    3       2211
```

I need to be able to iterate through the table (using sql:select or via a function or something in a jsp) so seconds becomes ddd:hh:mm:ss (days, hours, minutes, seconds).

I was using SEC_TO_TIME as part of the select statement which created the table but this maxes out at 858 hours so I think it needs to be a separate function or something.

What's the simplest way of doing this, I am a newbie so please provide as much explanation as possible.

Regards
Ralph

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to transfer the seconds to the language which will process the displayed values and convert it there. It's unnecessary logic to perform on the database layer, unless there's no other frontend.

EDIT: You want to use javascript, so here's a suggestion for JS.

```js
var seconds = 330364;
var duration = moment.duration(seconds, 'seconds');
var formatted = duration.format("D hh:mm:ss");
console.log(formatted); // 3 19:46:04
```

```html
<!-- Moment.js library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- moment-duration-format plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have seen a few javascript functions but I believe they are mostly untested because they throw multiple errors, I wondered whether anyone had a tried / tested one

Comment: If you wish to use javascript, I suggest you check out `moment.js`. There's at least one plugin I know of that does what you need. [moment-duration-format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/)

Comment: Thanks, I put the var lines in a scriplet and I get invalid character constant on 'seconds' (I am definitely a newbie)

Comment: Be aware that you can not use javascript inside if statements in JSP, javascript should be considered to be as static as html when you write JSP, because JSP will first process on the server, and then the javascript will run when the user loads the page. Not exactly sure what your error means here, I'd need to see an example of what it looks like on your end to be sure.

Comment: You need to use a script block for the javascript lines as well. See an example of how to do that here: [W3C <script> tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)

Comment: Thanks, now have your code in a script bock, how do I call it from within my jsp (i need to pass in the seconds as a variable and then printn the converted value), need a lot of help as you can see

Comment: you can insert the seconds into the javascript code like you would display text on a page with JSP normally. If we assume you have the seconds in a variable called `jspseconds` it could look like this: `var seconds = <%= out.print(jspseconds) %>;` - I'm a bit rusty on JSP syntax myself, but something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks but I need to pass the duration in seconds into your code (by calling your code as a function) and then retrieve the resulting formatted data, my knowledge on how to do that is at newbie level.

Comment: As I said, javascript executes after JSP, so there is no way for you tu use javascript to get that formatting, and then use it in JSP again. You have to make a JSP function for that. But if your goal is simply to display it to the user, you can use the javascript.

Comment: can someone tell me the easiest way to iterate through my table with a select statement (in JSTL sql:query) and convert the seconds to ddd:hh:mm:ss) as that iteration continues (without using SEC_TO_TIME)